# How to identify which database the user is using in hive CLI ?

Tags: hive

Is there any way to identify which database the user is using while using the command line interface ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To know which database user in

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.current.db=true
```

or start hive with

```
hive --hiveconf hive.cli.print.current.db=true
```

then the prompt will display

```
hive (db_name)>
```

Comment: how about in beeline?

Comment: How can do this for beeline?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to know the current database. One temporary in cli and second one is persistently.

1) in CLI just enter this command: **set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;**

2) In hive-site.xml paste this code:

```
    <property>
    <name>hive.cli.print.current.db</name>
    <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

In second scenario, you can automatically display the Hive dabatabase name when you open terminal.

Answer (score 5):

**Set hive.cli.print.current.db=true**; sets the property in current hive session only. If one is out of the session the setting would be reset to default(false).

To be able to see the database name consistently accross sessions and users, root user can create .hiverc file in /etc/hive/conf with required parameter values. In this case add set hive.cli.print.current.db=true; These settings are now applied across all the users logging into hive CLI.

if the user is not root user, create .hiverc file in home directory /home/<>.The settings would be effective across all the hive sessions for the user.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way (if there's table in the db):

```
desc extended {table_name};
```

From the output, dbName is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

while updating the conf property set hive.cli.print.current.db=true will show the current DB for the current session..

updating the .hiverc file with the above property will keep showing the current db for all the sessions.

Answer (score 2):

```
1)Permanent solution: 
Change this property in hive-site.xml file under HIVE_HOME/conf folder

   <property>
    <name>hive.cli.print.current.db</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Whether to include the current database in the Hive prompt.
    </description>
    </property>
2)Temporary solution:
go to hive prompt enter this
    hive> set hive.cli.print.current.db=True
```

Answer (score 1):

For keeping the database name persistent in the hive cli.

Add  set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;  to .hiverc file.

If the .hiverc is not present under hive/conf then create one.

It wont reflect if one tries to add in hive-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

For beeline use this command:
select current_database();